# Python Function debugging

Tags: python

The function **def shift(list_numbers)** takes a list of numbers as a parameter.

The function works like this -

- move every element in the list to the right; i.e. the value in element 0 is stored in element 1, the value in element 1 is stored in element 2, and so on. The value in the last element is stored in element 0.

**The function makes changes in place (i.e. change the list that is passed to the function. It should not create a new list and it should not return anything).**

eg:

```
list_numbers = [0, 2, 7]
shift(list_numbers)
print(list_numbers)

output - [7, 0, 2]
```

The code I have written below does not seem to be working, can someone help me figure out what's wrong?

```
def shift(list_numbers):
return list_numbers[::-1]
```

Comment: Well, the function doesn’t even attempt to do anything of what you described.

Comment: `list_numbers[::-1]` returns *reversed* list, it's not what you're asked to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your exercise says:

1. Operate in place (changing argument passed by caller inplace so the change is visible to the caller in the `list` they passed to you, while returning nothing), and
2. Rotate the elements one to the right

Your code:

1. Returns a *new* `list` leaving the caller's *unchanged*, and
2. Returns the *reversed* `list`, not a single-element *rotation* of the `list`

The correct way to implement this that follows both instructions is:

```
def shift(list_numbers):
    list_numbers.insert(0, list_numbers.pop())
```

which pops the final element off the `list` and then inserts it as the first element (shifting all the existing elements to the right to make room).

Comment: Nit: if the empty list is a valid argument, you'll have to handle that separately, since `[].pop()` will raise an `IndexError`.

Comment: @chepner: True. The OP would need to give an expected behavior for that case though; it's wholly possible the correct behavior *is* to die with an `IndexError`. If it's not (should silently do nothing), the solution can just be to make the body `if list_numbers: list_numbers.insert(0, list_numbers.pop())` (or catch the `IndexError` and `pass`, hardly matters).